# To use the API Location service, is it necessary to be authenticated on the cell phone with a Google account?

Tags: java, android, android-studio, apk, fusedlocationproviderapi

I'm using a Google API called "FusedLocationProvider" to get real-time location and coordinate updates.

I made a code in Android Studio JAVA, which allowed me to get the location in real time on the Cell Phone, except that every time I was going to test the location in the app, I could only test it if I had any Play Services apk installed on the phone or had a Google account logged into the phone.

Would anybody know any answer, if it is necessary to use API of locations that it is necessary even the user to be authenticated with google account synchronized on the cell phone?

Answer (score 0):

Well, technically the answer to your question is simple - it is not *necessary*.

And what's worth mentioning is that Google simply could not force you to use their API in Android, be it related to locations or any other part of the system - this is because of how the Android OS was designed from the ground up.

Google hasn't got any special privileges here and technically any company could very well duplicate their services. There are actually many real world Android devices working without any of the big G's "Play Services".

But as long as you choose to utilize some company's API service, of course you can always be limited to play by that company's rules. So this is a kind of a deal - Google offers to make your developer's life much easier by providing you their `FusedLocationProvider`, but for it they also demand that authentication and you are not totally ok with that but for me this is fair. This was their right to demand something from you for thee service they provided you.

After all you are not and probably will never be *forced* to use the Fused provider at all and I think there are dozens of alternatives. I believe many companies chose that path in the past and have created their own location managers. I google'd for a minute just for the sake of this post and already came across 1 example of an open-sourced alternative: https://github.com/lostzen/lost (not sure if authors still support it though, but still the code is there and it's public!)